# How to detect if a Window handle belongs to a VCL or not?

Tags: delphi

I'm writing a Office addin, and I need to **reliably** determine if win32 `window handle` is a handle of a `VCL` (a `control` or a `form`, whatsoever) of my Addin, or it's handle of any windows of Microsoft Office itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `IsVCLControl` in `Controls` unit. ([documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.IsVCLControl))

Comment: Thank you TOnDrej, it doesn't exist in earlier version of Delphi, however, on the page you provided I found FindControl, and I think I can utilize that function :)